# Documentation / getting started on ember.js version 1.13

Tags: ember.js

I like to use the latest released version of ember.js when I create my new app. That is version 1.13 now. I like to use this version so the transition to version 2.0 will be easy when it is released.
I just got latest version of ember-cli (using npm) and created a new ember project. But it created a project with ember version 1.12.
Also, the guides on the ember site target version 1.12 only.

How do I get started creating a project with version 1.13?
Is there a "getting started" tutorial for ember version 1.13?
What's the difference in filestructure between 1.12 and 1.13?

The Glimmer engine is new in 1.13. How do I use that? Are the templates still *.hbs?

Comment: Just wait some days for new ember-cli release. It will be with ember 1.13.1 https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/4276a0a20e6f85a20b652a7113a52c3e5f454556

Comment: You could follow 1.12 docs + changes (http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html). Yes, templates are still *.hbs.

Comment: The Ember team is a bit slow with their guides/docs

Answer (score 1):

[Ember CLI `v1.13.1`](http://www.ember-cli.com/#changelog) was released today, and that version comes with the current stable releases Ember `1.13.3` and Ember Data `1.13.5`.

The Ember.js core team was stretched a bit thin implementing all of the features that landed on `1.13` so the guides suffered a bit. However, [API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/) have been available for a while. You can also consult [the deprecations](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_deprecations-added-in-1-13) for `1.13`. The guides also provide a lot of information, both the [Ember `1.13` release post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html) and the [Ember Data `1.13` release post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html).

Hope that at least partially addressed your concerns.